# Renaming Column with name count( distinct( id )) in Hive Table

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I forget to give alias to a derived column while creating a table in HIVE from SELECT Statement.

```
CREATE TABLE temp AS (SELECT date, count(distinct(id)) FROM some_table GROUP BY date);
```

Now I want to query on the newly created temp table with filters on the derived column, I don't want to drop the table and run the same query again with alias for the derived column.

How can I filter on the column count(distinct(id)), or rename that column?

Answer (score 2):

You can see column names using `DESCRIBE`:

```
DESCRIBE temp;    
col1                    string                                      
_c1                     bigint
```

Then just rename the column:

```
ALTER TABLE temp CHANGE `_c1` `cnt` bigint;
```

Or use `_c1` column name:

```
SELECT `_c1` FROM temp2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

`` ALTER TABLE yourtable CHANGE `columnname` `newname` BIGINT; ``

Comment: You forgot `column_type` parameter